# Sort by Title button in Rails issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a movie list app where I can add lists of movies. On the list show page, where it displays the movies in that list, I'd like to have a button that sorts the movies in the list by title. I'm currently getting a routing error - No route matches [POST] "/lists/7". I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My movie model:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_movies
  has_many :lists, through: :list_movies

  def self.order_list(sort_order)
    if sort_order == 'title' || sort_order.blank?
      order(title: :asc)
    elsif sort_order == 'rating'
      order(rating: :asc)
    else
      order(created_at: :asc)
    end
  end

end
```

My controller action in lists_controller:

```
  def show
    @list_movies = @list.movies
    @list_movies.order_list(params[:sort_by])
  end
```

And my button on the lists show page:

```
<%= button_to "Sort By Title", list_path(@list, sort_by: "title"), class: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-space' %>
```

Am I doing something wrong with the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button_to` sends a `POST` request. Probably you should use `link_to` or use `method: :get` in the `button_to`

```
<%= button_to "Sort By Title", list_path(@list, sort_by: "title"), method: :get, class: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-space' %>
```

**OR**

```
<%= link_to "Sort By Title", list_path(@list, sort_by: "title"), class: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-space' %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your link_to, but now nothing happens when I click the button. The URL changes, but nothing happens on screen.